# How to count the number of documents filtered by a query in Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, database, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get the number of documents in a collection but **filtered by a query**.

I want to know the # of games *where my "Opponent_level" was "Worst"* than me. And: the number of times that I won *against "worst" opponents*.

I need this queries:

```
colRef= db
                .collection("users").document(currentUID)
                .collection("gamesession").document(currentGameSession)
                .collection("games");

Query query_opp_win = colRef.whereEqualTo("OpponentLvl", "Worst").whereEqualTo("Result", "Win");
Query query_opp_worst = colRef.whereEqualTo("OpponentLvl", "Worst");
```

I know how to retrieve the # number of games but not how to apply the queries to get the number :(

I read about **querySnapshot.size()** but I dont understand yet how to apply it to my code or what I have to change.

```
colRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    int counter = 0;
                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                        counter++;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Number: "+counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually execute the query that you defined in your first bit of code, then count the results of it as you show in your second bit of code.  You can't count anything at all without executing the query with `get()` as you are already showing.

```
query_opp_win.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            int counter = 0;
            for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                counter++;
            }
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Number: "+counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

See how I just took the `query_opp_win` and substituted it into the code you provided.

There is very little difference between counting the number of documents in a collection and counting the number of documents from a filtered query.  They are both essentially just making a query.  A CollectionReference is itself a Query object with no filters.

Comment: Thanks! It worked well c: pretty easy as you explained, just put the query.get()